# objectivec: fb post comment error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, comments, http-post

I created an ios application and want to post a comment to an article and to the comment of this article. But I can't get it work.

- Comment an article: I test with the graph "post_id/comments" using the post_id that I found on the page of "Object Debug". 
  I got error "500" when I posted by ios SDK and

  > {"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

when I posted by `https://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/comments`

- Post a sub comment to a comment: I used graph "commentID/comments", I got error 400 when I posted by ios sdk, and

  > {"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid fbid.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

when I posted to `https://graph.facebook.com/{commentID}/comments`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is correct but just you need to have problem is with Authentication.

Before comment or any post you must be logged or your session must be active. Check weather your session is active or not.

First of all call `[myDelegate authenticateFacebookUser];` and then call method to post a comment.

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)